# iPad magic keyboard language switch delay

Tags: keyboard, ipad, language, magic-keyboard-ipad

How do I fix the lag when switching a language on an iPad when connected to a magic keyboard (the one that works like a case too).

When I switch the language it takes a second or two before I can type in a space which is especially annoying as I'm constantly switching back and forth. Instead, iPad just ignores the fact that I pressed the space and I have two words collided.

Comment: You don't say what method you are using to switch of the 3 possible: Fn/Globe, Control Space, or Caps Lock (for Latin vs non-Latin).  Does using one of these work better for you than the others?

Comment: I use Control Space. Caps Lock I can't use as I find this rather unique. And with Globe it works kind of the same. I'd say until the language switch popup is gone it doesn't react on Space button.